# Haskell Lambda expression and matching types

Tags: haskell, lambda

I need a bit of help here. On the last line of code i always got a type match error but i dont understand why 'cause it seems to be good...
isGroupInscr(x)(y) return true or false and i compare it to True so no mismatch...
Can you give me some advices? :)

```
isGroupInscr :: GroupeCours -> Inscription -> Bool
isGroupInscr sigleGroup sigleInscr =  getSigle(sigleGroup) /= getSigle2(sigleInscr)

filtreGroupInscr :: [GroupeCours] -> [Inscription] -> [GroupeCours]
filtreGroupInscr listGroupe listInscr = filter (\x y -> isGroupInscr(x)(y) == True) listGroupe
```

error :

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
              with actual type ‘Inscription -> Bool’
• The lambda expression ‘\ x y -> isGroupInscr (x) (y) == True’
  has two arguments,
  but its type ‘GroupeCours -> Bool’ has only one
  In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely
    ‘(\ x y -> isGroupInscr (x) (y) == True)’
  In the expression:
    filter (\ x y -> isGroupInscr (x) (y) == True) listGroupe
```

Thanks

Comment: You do not need a lambda expression here: simply `isGroupInscr` is enough as first argument in `filter`.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the whole program? (Or provide a link to the source in [some pastebin](https://hastebin.com)?)

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without the type definitions and the specification -- what are you trying to do? You are not using the `listInscr` argument at all, so this looks quite wrong. Probably you need to either `zip` the two lists and then filter, or search whether a course occurs in the incriptions using `any` or custom recursion.

Comment: `filter` usually takes only one-argument-functions

Comment: use list comprehensions (like, `filter p xs` is `[ x | x <- xs, p xs ]`). they are much more visual and immediate, it's harder to write a wrong expression with them. for instance, where is `y` coming from into your lambda function?

Comment: It's hard to tell what do you want to do however yout program does not typecheck because filter is of type

    (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

however you are invoking it with function of type

    GroupeCours -> Inscription -> Bool

as first argument. As it was stated in previous comment filter expects one-argument function, not two-argument function. Depending on what do you want to do, you may use uncurry or reformulate isGroupInsc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to partially apply

```
isGroupInscr :: GroupeCours -> Inscription -> Bool
```

to get a function that has type

```
Inscription -> Bool
```

to be able to use with `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`

---

**Guessing** from type of the function, I think what you want is

```
isGroupInscr :: GroupeCours -> Inscription -> Bool
isGroupInscr sigleGroup sigleInscr =  getSigle sigleGroup /= getSigle2 sigleInscr

filtreGroupInscr :: [GroupeCours] -> [Inscription] -> [GroupeCours]
filtreGroupInscr (g:gs) (l:ls) = if isGroupInscr g l 
                                 then g : filtreGroupInscr gs ls
                                 else []
filtreGroupInscr _      _      = []
```

Other possible guess

```
filtreGroupInscr listGroupe listInscr  
    = [g | g <- listGroupe , l <- listInscr, isGroupInscr g l]
```

Also, noted that you don't have to use `()` for calling function unless it really need. Haskell use space as function application.

---

**Side-note** : With haskell `undefined` magic, I am able to load the incomplete code in GHCi to do the type-checking.

code test3.hs

```
data GroupeCours = GroupeCours
data Inscription = Inscription
data Single = Single deriving Eq

getSigle :: GroupeCours -> Single
getSigle = undefined

getSigle2 :: Inscription -> Single
getSigle2 = undefined

isGroupInscr :: GroupeCours -> Inscription -> Bool
isGroupInscr sigleGroup sigleInscr =  getSigle sigleGroup /= getSigle2 sigleInscr

filtreGroupInscr :: [GroupeCours] -> [Inscription] -> [GroupeCours]
filtreGroupInscr (g:gs) (l:ls) = if isGroupInscr g l 
                                then g : filtreGroupInscr gs ls
                                else []
filtreGroupInscr _      _      = []

filtreGroupInscr' :: [GroupeCours] -> [Inscription] -> [GroupeCours]
filtreGroupInscr' listGroupe listInscr  
    = [g | g <- listGroupe , l <- listInscr, isGroupInscr g l]
```

GHCi in action

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /data/works/dotfiles/ghci
Prelude> :l test3.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test3.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :t isGroupInscr 
isGroupInscr :: GroupeCours -> Inscription -> Bool
*Main> :t filtreGroupInscr
filtreGroupInscr :: [GroupeCours] -> [Inscription] -> [GroupeCours]
*Main> :t filtreGroupInscr'
filtreGroupInscr'
  :: [GroupeCours] -> [Inscription] -> [GroupeCours]
```